# How to use variable in a modal window?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

In my modal window, I would like get the ID field of the data row, and use this ID in variable in a select MYSQL. Like this:

```
$id= $row["id"];
$query = "SELECT * FROM storage WHERE id='$id'";
```

If I do this:

```
$id="<input type='text' id='id' name='id' />";
```

I can display this ID, but can't use as a variable php in my modal.

Comment: You need to show us all the relevant code and explain what you want to do a little better. It's very unclear at the moment.

Comment: I can get the data to the modal but what are you trying to do with it?  Show your code.

Comment: Hi, can you help me ? I add my code . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM storage WHERE id={$id}");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
echo '<input type="text" id="'.$row['id'].'" name="'.$row['id'].'" />';
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you are using this modal on the same page of the MySQL consult you can do this:

```
<input type="text" id="id" name="id" value = value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Here is part of my code:

```
<!-- MODAL -->
<div class="modal fade" id="editor-modal">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<form class="modal-content form-horizontal" id="editor">
<div class="modal-header">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
   <h4 class="modal-title" id="editor-title">Add</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<input type="number" id="id" name="id" readonly/>
```

My problem begin here. How to use the Row id in a select sql ?

```
    <?php // I get a field in array. ex (1,6,8,) which are the id of the selected places coming from another base.
   $id = ???

   $query = "SELECT * FROM storage_0 WHERE id='id'";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {
   $exp_string = $row["select_type"];
   $exp_arr = explode(',', $exp_string);
   for ($i = 0;$i < count($exp_arr);$i++)
   {
   $val['value_' . $i] = $exp_arr[$i];
   }
   }
   ?>
```

After, I can display in my modal the list of selected places.

```
    <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" class="hidden"/>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="type" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Types<span style="padding-left:5px;"><a title="Ajouter un Type" href="../type/editing.php?item=0"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-1x"></i></a></span></label>
<div class="col-sm-9">
<?PHP
   $requete = $pdo->prepare('
   SELECT id, type
   FROM stock_type
   WHERE del = 0
   ORDER BY id ASC ;');
   $requete->execute();
   $datas = $requete->fetchAll();

   foreach ($datas as $data)
   {
   if (in_array(intval($data->id) , $val))
   {$selected = "checked";}else{$selected = "";}
   ?>
<span id="results"></span>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" name="select_type[]" id="select_type" value="<?php echo $data->id; ?>" <?php echo $selected; ?>><?php echo $data->type; ?>
</label>
<?php } ?>
<!--...-->
```